# Why entity framework results are reference type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reference

I`m using C# entity framework 6 and there is a problem. after run a query and changed an item values, others items also changed automatically.

Please see the screenshot. Why items[0].C.Tag is "Red"? How can I resolve this problem?
[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it looks like you've got both of your database `Person` objects connected to the same city, `ID = 1` ("New York"). If my understanding is correct, then it would make sense when you change the `Tag` for `City1` to "Red" it will change for both `Person` objects.

Comment: It seems [that is by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) but can be changed based on how you setup your relations.

Answer (score 1):

This is because items[0].C and items[1].C points to the same object .items[0].C and items[1].C is the object for first row of city table. Both the Persons table entries has same cityID so they obviously point to same city with Id 1. EF creates one object per Id (primary key).

Comment: thanks. But how can I do this with 2 pointer?

Answer (score 1):

After 7 days, I added AsNoTracking() and all things are OK. So objects are not same

```
var items = (from P in db.tbl_Persons
             join C in db.tbl_Cities on P.CityID equals C.ID
             select new { P, C }).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```